# Missing controller add option, Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022

No options:

[image: No options]

Installed packages:

[image: Installed packages]

Hi, I just downloaded Visual Studio 2022 and can't seem to find the add options, specifically add controller when I right click on add as shown in picture. I have installed just about all the packages and even the MVC 4 package as well but still no luck. This is driving me insane as its delaying my whole project. I have looked around but cant seem to find a way to fix this. Please help

Comment: Switch away from the Folder view. This option is only available in Solution view

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I found the issue, I think it has to do with what option was used when creating the project since I made it in VS Code and tried to migrate to VS, it just didn't allow all the options to work.